# AsyncTask questions

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I was reading things about `AsyncTask`. It was understandable to me, but immediately two concerns came up to my mind:

Let say I have a class and an interface:

```
public MyInterface<T>
{
    void done(T result);
}

public MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface<String>
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        R.getViewByID(R.....);

        //...

        beginTask(urls);
    }

    private void beginTask(URL[] urls)
    {
        ATask task = new ATask(this);
        task.execute(urls);
    }

    @Override
    void done()
    {
        System.out.println("done!");
    }
}
```

And the `AsyncTask` class:

```
public ATask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>
{
    MyInterface<String> handler = null;
    private StringBuilder fetchedResult = new StringBuilder();

    ATask(MyInterface<T> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackGround(URL urls...)
    {
        URL url = urls[0];
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler<String>();

        String result = null;

        try
        {
            result = client.execute(request, handler);
            fetchResult.append(result);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return fetchResult.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        handler.done(result);
    }
}
```

All is well. But the concerns that came to me were:

> 1.)
>
> What if for some reasons the `Activity` (`MyActivity`) that calls the `AsyncTask` 
>   (`ATask`) gets destroyed and when `ATask` is finished and then calls done(); in the destroyed Activity? How could we prevent
>   this from happening or is there a way to re-create the destroyed
>   `Activity`? What would be the best practice here?
>
> 2.)
>
> Another scenario: What if the background task takes a long time (intended, even though
>   the App is no longer in view) in `doInBackground`? Would it then keep holding onto a 
>   reference of this Activity (MyActivity) for as long when the Activity (MyActivity) should be destroyed for memory's sake (i.e., when onStop() needs to be called)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) As per the documentation :

`onStop()` -> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one.

`ondestroy()` -> The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space

So you need to decide when do you want to call your `task.cancel()`, it may depend on your business logic.

2.) As per the documentation `AsyncTask` should be used for operations running only for a very few seconds. Whenever an `AsyncTask`/`Thread` is running and your activity gets destroyed then memory is leaked because they still hold the reference of your activity. To avoid any leak declare the `AsyncTask`/`Thread` as a **private static inner class** and in `onDestroy()` close your thread by `t.close` and in case of `AsyncTask` set your activity to `null` `mActivity = null` so in both the cases your activity is now eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you. I have read somewhere that "Your background task is having a reference to your Context / Activity! You're leaking memory!", hence the question. Hope I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you have to override application onDestroy or activity onStop methods and call task.cancel(). So you need to keep reference to your task object.

Comment: Thanks for response. But for case #2, is there a way to let the background task run, let the Activity gets destroyed (save memory) and when this long task in finished, re-create the Activity dynamically and then call done() on this Activity? I have heard that even an orientation change would cause the Activity to get re-created, if I am not mistaken (but this is not a case I mentioned in my question. It just came to me while typing this comment out).

Comment: Create static boolean field isRunning in activity and override methods onStart(isRunning = true) and onStop(isRunning = false) of the activity(). In postExecute of the AsyncTask check if activity is not running just create intent with applicationContext(BTW you need to keep applicationContext too by overriding onCreate in class that extends Application) and your activity class like applicationContext.startActivity(new Intent(applicationContext, MyActivity.class)).

Comment: Could you elaborate that in your answer?